# Invoke public function from internal/private function?

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if I'm missing something or not but I attempted to do the following:

```
(function() {
    var thing = function() {
        var doIt = function() {
            console.log("just do it");
            this.updateValue(5);
        };

        return {
            updateValue: function(val) {
                console.log('updating value: ' + val);
            },

            go: function() {
                doIt();
            }
        }
    };

    var t = thing();
    t.go();
}())
```

This results in "just do it" showing up in the console followed by an error b/c it says "updateValue" is not a function.

I was wondering, can an internal/private function (e.g. "doIt") invoke a public function (e.g. "updateValue")? Perhaps this is just bad design and you should never really want to do this and I've actually refactored my code to avoid/not do this but I was curious if it was possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use call/apply to explicitly specify the context for `this` (like @SLaks and @Alnitak) mentioned or else define the function at the beginning and then add it as a property to the returned object:

```
var thing = function() {
    var updateValue = function () { /* */ },
        doIt = function() {
            console.log("just do it");
            updateValue(5);
    };

    return {
        updateValue: updateValue, // minor duplication here
        go: function() {
            doIt();
        }
    };
};
```

If the minor duplication annoys you, you can also do this:

```
var thing = function() {
    var exposed = {
        updateValue: function(val) {
            console.log('updating value: ' + val);
        },
        go: function() {
            doIt();
        }
    }, doIt = function() {
        console.log("just do it");
        exposed.updateValue(5);
    };

    return exposed;
};
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who put in there answers. @SLaks and @Alnitak I see what you mean, thanks for pointing that out.

@andreas-grech - I chose your response as the "answer" b/c I like the idea of "exposed", I just named my "api" :)

Comment: I usually try to avoid the `this` as much as possible because it can bite you if you're not very careful with it.
If you want to know more about it, read something like this: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 0):

Writing `doIt()`, calls the function in the global context, so `this` is the `window` object.

You need to write `doIt.call(this)` to pass your `this` as the context for `doIt`.

Comment: gah, you added that while I was writing my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Per @SLaks answer, `this` is incorrect when invoked by `doIt()`.

Instead, try:

```
doIt.call(this);
```